# Making clear the meaning of “Begin, be bold, and venture to be wise.”

Tags: meaning, quotes

Which of these two interpretations is correct about the following quote?

> “Begin, be bold, and venture to be wise.” by Horace

1. If you want to become a wise person, do these three things: Begin, be bold, venture
2. Begin. Be bold. Dare to be a wise person.

namely, "to be wise" belongs to "begin,bold and venture" or just "venture"?
Please let me know the reasons of choosing the right answer.

Comment: I don't really understand the point of this question. Would it make any difference if someone who knows the original Latin says [Pam Pegram's exposition of this quotation](https://www.pampegram.com/master-what-matters/2013/07/15/begin-be-bold-and-venture-to-be-wise#:%7E:text=Be%20the%20one%20who%20creates,important%20part%20of%20the%20quote.) *doesn't* reflect Horace's intention?

Comment: I think context is important here, as well. Is Horace guiding the reader to a very specific goal, or is this meant more generally, as good life advice? (And please be more specific about the source of the phrase: which of Horace's works does this quote come from?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Author and speaker [Pam Pegram's exposition](https://www.pampegram.com/master-what-matters/2013/07/15/begin-be-bold-and-venture-to-be-wise#:%7E:text=Be%20the%20one%20who%20creates,important%20part%20of%20the%20quote.) of this quotation correctly has three bullet points headed:

> - **Begin.**  Yes, begin. Today is a new day.  We can decide to do today what we have failed to do....
> - **Be bold.**  Don’t wait for opportunities.  Don’t set back and wait for someone to ....
> - **Venture to be wise** ... the most important part of the quote. [Actively] [s]eek wisdom....

The inclusion of a listing (Oxford) comma would be necessary to indicate the alternative sense (Begin, be bold, and venture, to be wise.) according to Gricean demands for clarity. And intransitive / non-catenative *venture* usually takes a prepositional phrase.

The catenation [venture] [to V] is shown in this extract from [Oxford University Press Encyclopedia.com](https://www.encyclopedia.com/humanities/dictionaries-thesauruses-pictures-and-press-releases/venture-0):

> *venture*
>
> ∎ dare to do or say something that may be considered audacious (often
> used as a polite expression of hesitation or apology):
>
> - [M]ay I venture to add a few comments?
> - I ventured to write to her.

Answer (score 0):

Neither is correct.

> “Begin, be bold, and venture to be wise.”

can be paraphrased as

*Start, be brave and assertive, and take risks **in order** to become wise.*

OED To venture =

**1.a.** transitive. **To risk the loss of (something); to expose to the chance of loss or injury, esp. in the hope of obtaining some advantage or gain; to hazard, risk, or stake.**

Comment: Thanks, but it's not still clear for me. Please see the updates in the question and modify your answer according it.

Comment: The point is that the "to" in "to be wise" is a preposition and an ellipsis: it is a short form of "in order to", which introduces an adjectival phrase.